# Xcode: Multiple versions of a static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I'm trying to create a project in Xcode (6.0.1) that uses two versions of a static library. Therefore I have created a directory structure that looks similar to this:

```
+ include
  |-- VersionA
      |-- foo.h
      |-- bar.h
  |-- VersionB
      |-- foo.h
      |-- bar.h

+ lib
  |-- VersionA
      |-- foo.a
      |-- bar.a
  |-- VersionB
      |-- foo.a
      |-- bar.a
```

The headers foo.h and bar.h in the both directories are similar, whereas the executables are different. In order to include a certain header, I (non-recursively) added the the include directory to the search path an included like this:

```
#include "VersionA/foo.h"   // or this:
#include "VersionB/bar.h"
```

Now the question: How does Xcode decide which Mach-O fat (.a) file to link for a certain header file? How does this assignment work, and how can I influence it?

EDIT:

I get no duplicate symbol linking errors, although the linker looks into both lib directories. Since the header files have include guards like

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
...
```

I also get no errors regarding redefinition. If I change one include guard i.e.

#ifndef FOO_H_VERSION1

there are errors at compile time (Sematic Issue, Redefinition of 'FOO_SOMETHING'). This makes sense to me and indicates that it might not be best practice to duplicate header files.

Nevertheless, for my project I **need** two versions of a static library. What would be a reasonable way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including a header file does not automatically include or link a library - you indicate which libraries you'd like to be linked in the "Link Binaries with Libraries" section of your Build Phases.

In your case, you will simply need to add all of the libraries and then use the corresponding header file where relevant.

However, you've said that these are different versions of the same library. If your libraries contain methods of the same name, the linker will complain about that. With this in mind, you should reconsider whether or not it is seriously necessary to include separate versions of the same library - if there is an issue with one/both of the libraries that's stopping you from using just one, it may be more useful (and less stressful, ultimately) to try and resolve that problem.

Comment: The funny thing is, that the linker does not complain about duplicate symbols although it apparently links both library directories. But - since the header files have the same content - there should be duplicates, right?

Comment: Ok, you were right, it was quiet easy to use only one version. Thx!

Comment: @Simon Glad that it works. In regard to your first comment, under most circumstances the linker does not look for functions in your linked libraries unless you've actually used them. If you're using separate functions which don't have duplicates between the two library versions, there should be no problem. If not - that's strange - just hope that it keeps working!

Answer (score 0):

Header files are not "linked" to anything.  Here is what happens.  You create a promise for a whole bunch of different methods via headers, and then give that promise to the linker.  One of the linker's jobs is to search all of the artifacts that you have included in your project to make sure that each of those methods is actually there.  If one is missing, you will get a missing symbol error.  If both libraries define a method with the same name, you will get a duplicate symbol error.  In the end those .a files don't exist.  Everything is put together into one binary file.